# Powershell command for Event id count and warning erros

Tags: powershell

((Get-EventLog -LogName System -InstanceId 1006,1007,455,6003 -EntryType 'Warning').count)- This command is running but i want this event id count for last 2 hours how shall i modify this could someone help in this case?

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help Get-EventLog -Parameter After`. however, you may want to switch to the somewhat faster `Get-Help Get-WinEvent -Parameter FilterHashtable`.

Answer (score 0):

This command does the job:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="System";Level = 3;StartTime=(get-date).AddHours(-2); Id=1006,1007,455,6003 }


Level values:

Comment         5
Information     4
Warning         3
Error           2
Critical        1
LogAlways       0
```

Get-WinEvent with FilterHastable has better performance than Get-EventLog

to count this just add count

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="System";Level = 3;StartTime=(get-date).AddHours(-2); Id=1006,1007,455,6003 }).count
```

Comment: This code is running but not able to get the count for the event ids. (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="System";Level = 3;StartTime=(get-date).AddHours(-2); Id=1006,1007,455,6003 }).could someone help in this case

Comment: to count just add .count, i have added the syntax